# Improve performance of concatenate/append

Tags: python, performance, numpy, concatenation

I have an array of shape similar to `(4, 7, 25000)`.  I need to concatenate along the first dimension, given some fixed indexes. The final array has thus a shape of `(7, 25000)`.

I've tried three approaches, and `np.concatenate()` is the fastest but since this code is used millions of times, it is still slow.

Is there any way to improve the performance of this operation?

```
import time as t
import numpy as np

# Define array and indexes
aa = np.random.uniform(-10, 10, (4, 7, 25000))
weights = np.array([.20, .5, .35, .05])
idxs = (weights * aa.shape[-1]).astype(int)
idxs = (idxs[0], idxs[0] + idxs[1], idxs[0] + idxs[1] + idxs[2])


def f1(aa):
    """Original using np.concatenate()"""
    bb = np.concatenate([
        aa[0][:, :idxs[0]], aa[1][:, idxs[0]:idxs[1]],
        aa[2][:, idxs[1]:idxs[2]], aa[3][:, idxs[2]:]], axis=1)


def f2(aa):
    """Define empty array first. Not faster"""
    bb = np.empty((7, 25000))
    bb[:, :idxs[0]] = aa[0][:, :idxs[0]]
    bb[:, idxs[0]:idxs[1]] = aa[1][:, idxs[0]:idxs[1]]
    bb[:, idxs[1]:idxs[2]] = aa[2][:, idxs[1]:idxs[2]]
    bb[:, idxs[2]:] = aa[3][:, idxs[2]:]


def f3(aa):
    """Use list appending and transposition. A *lot* slower"""
    bb = np.array(
        aa[0][:, :idxs[0]].T.tolist()
        + aa[1][:, idxs[0]:idxs[1]].T.tolist()
        + aa[2][:, idxs[1]:idxs[1] + idxs[2]].T.tolist()
        + aa[3][:, idxs[2]:].T.tolist()).T
```

Comment: Whatever solution you end up with, you should avoid chained indexing, `arr[][][]` creates multiple intermediate views of an array, and is inefficient.

Comment: Did not know that, thank you!

Comment: I don't think you'll get better performance than f1. your problem is that you are calling this millions of times: you should try to vectorize that instead.